# What should be the size of Training data set for machine-learning?

Tags: twitter, machine-learning, nlp, datumbox

1) I want to perform sentiment analysis on twitter tweets. So, I choose to use the **datumbox-framework**. I have small doubt what should be the size of my training samples? & if I'm collecting the training samples of positive,negative,neutral should I maintain the same size for all the training examples? (i.e., can I collect 10 pos,5 neg,15 neutral as my training sets or I should collect and maintain all of pos,neg,neutral of same size pos=10;neg=10;neutral=10 in my training set) algorithm I'm using for twitter sentiment.
is **navies Bayes**.

2) is there any size limit for training data set?

Comment: can i know the reason that why my question has given down vote ?

Comment: It has probably been down-voted since its a question which can lead to opinion based answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Training Set**: The set of data used to build the model.
Ideally, the dataset should not be biased in anyway and should contain all possibilities of cases that may appear in future.

Bigger the training set, the better the result. That is more the test cases in the training set, the better is your model. So try to cover as many pos, neg or neutral twits.

There is no ideal training set size. And there may never be a training set which would predict 100% of the test cases right, that's because ***the system doesn't understand sarcasm*** :D

And There is no size limit for a training set.

Note: Training set must be random, you must not use 10pos, 2neg, 3 neutral etc since that would make it biased.

A general suggestion: Use 60-70% for training and the rest for validation & testing.

Comment: thank you. Do I need to update my training set at some instance of time. I dont have any idea on how to work with validation and testing @AniMenon

Comment: You may improve your model at any time by considering a bigger training set. Validation is the process of checking how many records were classified correctly and examining how to improve the classification. Testing is the phase were you run new data on the trained model to find accuracy of the model.